# Is the Macbook Pro touch bar hardware accelerated?

Tags: macos, nstouchbar, macbookpro-touch-bar

Is the new [Macbook Pro touch bar](https://developer.apple.com/macos/touch-bar/) hardware accelerated? Will it support things like OpenGL contexts and the like?

Comment: Why the downvotes and the completely irrelevant close vote reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

You can imagine Touch Bar as another display on your MacBook Pro.

> The Touch Bar is a Retina display, like the screen of a MacBook Pro. To perform custom drawing or animation within the Touch Bar, follow the same best practices that you would on the screen.

In Interface Builder just add **Touch Bar View** component from Object Library to the Touch Bar.

> **Touch Bar View** - Instance of NSView to be used in Touch Bar.

Now you can just simply add you **OpenGL View** or **Scene Kit View** to your **Touch bar View**.